# How to Render partial on button click Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I want to render partial on button click in rails.
I have two controllers

1. Fields Controller
2. Operator Controller

When user click show on index.html.erb it will show a pop up with the content of index.html.erb of Operator Controller.

This is my button of index.html.erb of Fields Controller:

```
<%= link_to "Link" ,operators_index_path(:id => field_id, :field_name=>field_name), :remote => true %>
```

This is index method of Operators Controller:

```
class OperatorsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @operators = Api::AnalyticsQueryBuilderMetadataService::Operator.show(params[:id])
  end
end
```

This is the content of index.html.erb of Operator Controller which I want to show as pop up:

```
<%if @operators['items'].empty?%>
  <div class="error-handling-page">
  <div class="dialog">
    <div>
      <h1>No Operator Found</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
<%else%>
<table class ="table">
<thead>
    <th class ="head">Field Name</th>
    <th class ="head">Name</th>
    <th class ="head">Description</th>
</thead>
    <% @operators['items'].each do |data| %>
        
        <% @opId =  data['operators'] %>
        <% @opId.each do |value| %>
        <tr>
        <td><%= field_name %></td>
        <td><%= value['mnemonic']%></td>
        <td><%= value['description']%></td>
        </tr>
        <%end%>
    <%end%>
</tbody>
</table>
<%end%>
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with AJAX and UJS.

Here's [my favorite tutorial](https://www.rubyguides.com/2019/03/rails-ajax/).

If you want to be cutting-edge, Rails 7 has Hotwire, which can also do this. There are *many* Hotwire tutorials available via a quick Google search.

Answer (score 0):

For Rails, Hotwire is the tool you should research. In particular, you'll want to take advantage of turbo frames, which allow you to replace just a piece of the html page with what is returned by the controller.

An excellent resource to learn about Hotwire is [this page](https://www.hotrails.dev/turbo-rails).